# Solving solution set inequalities problems

Tags: inequality

I need some guidance with solving problems of the following nature:

$$|x^2-3x-1|<3$$

Instinctively, my way of solving it is splitting it into the following equations:

$$x^2-3x-1< 3$$

$$x^2-3x-1> -3$$

Solving $x^2-3x-1< 3$

$$x^2-3x-4< 0$$ 
$$(x+1)\ (x-4)< 0$$
$$x < -1$$
$$x < 4$$

Solving $x^2-3x-1> -3$

$$x^2-3x-1> -3$$
$$x^2-3x+2> 0$$
$$(x-2)(x-1)> 0$$
$$x > 2$$
$$x > 1$$

So, here $x < -1$ is a valid solution and $x > 1$ is also valid.

In addition, $x < 4$ is valid and $ x > 2$ is also valid.

So we have $-1 > x > 1$ and $2<x<4$.

Firstly, is this possible? Does any $x$ have to satisfy $-1 > x > 1$ and $2<x<4$ simultaneously? Or are these the ranges of allowed inputs? Like, $x$ can be $-2$ despite $2<-2<4$ is not true.

Secondly, WolframAlpha has the following numberline:

[image]

Which means I've not solved this correctly. So how do I solve these properly?

Comment: why $x<-1$ and $x<4$? take $x=-2$ you get $(-2+1)(-2-4)=6$, but you are saying $(-2+1)(-2-4)<0$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$(x+1)\ (x-4)< 0$$
$$x < -1$$
$$x < 4$$

Really? Did you try to plug in $x=-2$ to see if the inequality holds?

---

Remember, $a\cdot b<0$ if **exactly one** of the two numbers is negative. So, either $(x+1)$ is negative and $(x-4)$ is positive (which, since $x+1>x-4$, is impossible) or $x+1$ is positive and $x-4$ is negative.

You can also rewrite the inequality as

$$(x+1)\cdot(4-x)>0$$

and then use the fact that $a\cdot b>0$ if the sign of both numbers is equal.

---

You made the same mistake in the other inequality.

$$(x-2)(x-1)> 0$$
$$x > 2$$
$$x > 1$$

This excludes a lot of options, for ecample, $x=-100$ is also a perfectly valid solution

---

Your main mistake is that you go from

$$f(x)\cdot g(x) > 0$$

to

$$f(x)>0\text{ and }g(x)>0$$

which is a pretty big mistake. Remember, the product of two negative numbers is also positive! So, once you get to $$f(x)g(x)>0$$, you have two options:

1. $f(x)>0$ and $g(x)>0$
2. $f(x)<0$ and $g(x)<0$.

similarly, if you get to $f(x)g(x)<0$, the two options are

1. $f(x)>0$ and $g(x)<0$
2. $f(x)<0$ and $g(x)>0$.

Answer (score 0):

$$|x^2-3x-1|<3\Rightarrow -3<x^2-3x-1<3\\\Rightarrow -3<x^2-2(3/2)x+(3/2)^2-(3/2)^2-1<3\\\Rightarrow 1/4<(x-3/2)^2<25/4$$

Now you have two inequation:

1. $1/4<(x-3/2)^2\Rightarrow x-3/2<-1/2\space \text{or}\space x-3/2>1/2\Rightarrow x<1\space \text{or}\space x>2$.
2. $(x-3/2)^2<25/4\Rightarrow -5/2<x-3/2<5/2\Rightarrow x>-1\space \text{or} \space x<4$

Hence the final answer is $\{x\in\mathbb{R}: -1<x<1\space\text{and}\space 2<x<4\}\space\space\space\blacksquare$

Answer (score 0):

It's $$(x^2-3x-1)^2<3^2$$ or
$$(x^2-3x+2)(x^2-3x-4)<0$$ or
$$(x+1)(x-1)(x-2)(x-4)<0,$$ which gives the answer:
$$(-1,1)\cup(2,4).$$

Comment: very nice but OP has a problem in finding such ranges, so you may elaborate why you get $(-1,1)\cup (2,4)$

Comment: @MANMAID It's the intervals method. We'll put on the $x$- axis $-1$, $1$, $2$ and $4$. It's obvious that our expression is positive for $x>4$ and degrees of all points are odds. Thus, we have on $x$-axis: $+$, $-1$ ,$-$,$1$,$+$,$2$,$-$,$4$,$+$ and we can write the answer by seeing, where we have $-$. This method is very known and not needs elaborating.

Comment: I know that very well, but as you see OP wrote $(x+1)(x-4)<0$, implies $x<-1$ and $x<4$ (and it is not a typo as you see). that's why I suggested to elaborate it... anyway it's okk if you don't... just a suggestion!

Comment: @MANMAID If we wish to solve $(x+1)(x-4)<0$ only then we can put $-1$ and $4$ on $x$-axis and we have $+$, $-1$, $-$, $4$, $+$, which gives the answer: $-1<x<4$.